# Django query with existing format

Tags: django

I have model like below

```
class Books(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True)
```

How to query that will return

```
author1 - Book 1
       - Book 2
       - Book 3
author2 - Book4
        - Book5
```

Comment: A query does not contain such "hierarchy". A relational database always contains tables, and tables are filled with records that have the same columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query on a *relational* database does not work with a *hierarchy*. It always returns "flat records".

You can however fetch the records, and then render it accordingly, so:

```
def my_view(reques):
    authors = Author.objects.prefetch_related('books_set')
    return render(request, 'name-of-template.html', {'authors': authors})
```

then in the template, we can for example render this with:

```
<!-- name-of-template.html -->
<ul>
{% for author in authors %}
    <li>{{ author }}</li>
    <ul>
    {% for book in author.books_set.all %}
        <li>{{ book.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Book` instead of <s>`Books`</s>.